# How to append the file extension .pdf to a String entered by the user?

Tags: c#

I am coding a program that I need to save texts (from a rich text box) to a pdf.

I use iTextSharp and this is my code:

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("TitleOfPdf.pdf", FileMode.Create));//textBox1(in the form) assign here the title of the document
doc.Open(); //open the document in order to write inside.
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(richTextBox1.Text);
// Now adds the above created text using different class object to our pdf document
doc.Add(paragraph);
doc.Close();
```

I would like the title of the file to be *flexible* and be assigned by the user (from a text box).

If I change the line:

```
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("TitleOfPdf.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

to:

```
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Create));
```

then it works fine, **but** the file hasn't got the extension `.pdf`.

How I can make the title of the document *flexible* so the user can assign it, and the extension will be `.pdf`?

Comment: You know that you can concatenate strings? Like `textBox1.Text + ".pdf"`?

Comment: You could even check if `textBox1.Text` ends with `".pdf"` and only append it if needed, so you won't get `filename.pdf.pdf`. One way of doing it is to use `SubString(textBox1.Text.Length-4)`, another is to use a regular espression. Oh and filenames might be case sensitive on the file system, but for your own mental sanity check case insensitive. Beware of empty or null values of `textBox1.Text`, or if it is shorter than 4 characters. The exact code is left as an excercise to the reader.

Comment: Even though iTextSharp is mentioned, this question is not about pdf creation but about elementary C# programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the user mkl i found the answere. I had to put:

```
textBox1.Text + ".pdf"
```

Comment: But what if the user already puts `filename.pdf` in the textbox? Then your file will be `filename.pdf.pdf`.